# Will ALSA 1.0.25 version have time to enter 12.04

Tags: alsa, 12.04

ALSA version 1.0.25 which comes with many good updates landed today. Will it have time to enter 12.04 since it just so happen I have 2 Creative sound cards that as 1.0.25 mentions will work out of the box (instead of having no sound at all).

Comment: /me hands @Luis Alvarado Arch Linux - sorry with  your last 2 questions I could not resist. I have no idea as to either =)

Comment: hahaha. Sorry it's just that 12.04 might be the one to solve some problems I know some people are having and me included. I will have Arch Linux in mind although let's sshh about it. You never know if the top 10 league of justice are watching (Oli, Foss, Jorge, Stefano..)

Comment: For this one I would say your best bet is to file a bug report. It is always helpful if you can include a solution to the problem in the report (works in ALSA 1.0.25 ... ) , the developers appreciate that. They would probably include it if they can. The feature freeze has not yet passed =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.**

As for today, ALSA packages in Ubuntu Precise are in version **1.0.25**, which means that it did have time to be included in Precise, and, of course, that should mean that your sound carts will be supported in Ubuntu 12.04!